# Find minimum depth in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, interview-questions

**Description:**

Given a binary tree, find its minimum depth.

The minimum depth is the number of nodes along the shortest path from the root node down to the nearest leaf node.

Note: A leaf is a node with no children.

[Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-depth-of-binary-tree/description/)

**Code:**

```
class Solution {
    public int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) return 0;
        return recur(root, 1);
    }

    private int recur(TreeNode root, int depth) {
        if (root == null) return 0;
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            return depth;
        }
        int ldepth = recur(root.left, depth + 1);
        int rdepth = recur(root.right, depth + 1);

        // either left or right subtree was not a leaf node
        // ignore non leaf node.
        if (ldepth == 0 || rdepth == 0) {
            return Math.max(ldepth, rdepth);
        }
        else {
            return Math.min(ldepth, rdepth);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

I need to know if the given logic can be simplified?

Answer (score 1):

If by *simplification* you mean *optimization*, then only one thing came to my mind:

- Whenever you find a leaf node, remember its depth in `minmalFound` variable.
- When again you hit the next leaf node you compare its depth with previously remembered node. And save the minimum of both into `minmalFound`.

And the main logic to add is whenever you are searching a certain path and find out that the depth becomes as great as the existing `minmalFound`, then you stop searching that path.

Here is code to demonstrate this technique:

```
public class Solution {
    public static int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
        reccallscount = 0;
        minmalFound = -1;
        if (root == null)
            return 0;
        return recur(root, 1);
    }

    public static boolean doFaster = false;
    private static int minmalFound = -1;
    private static int reccallscount = 0;

    private static int recur(TreeNode root, int depth) {
        reccallscount++;
        if (root == null) return 0;
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            if (minmalFound == -1) {
                minmalFound = depth;
            } else {
                minmalFound = Math.min(minmalFound, depth);
            }
            return depth;
        }

        if (doFaster) {
            if (minmalFound != -1 && depth + 1 >= minmalFound) {
                return minmalFound * 2;
            }
        }

        int ldepth = recur(root.left, depth + 1);
        int rdepth = recur(root.right, depth + 1);

        // either left or right subtree was not a leaf node
        // ignore non leaf node.
        if (ldepth == 0 || rdepth == 0) {
            if (ldepth != 0) {
                minmalFound = Math.min(minmalFound, ldepth);
            } else if (rdepth != 0) {
                minmalFound = Math.min(minmalFound, rdepth);
            }
            return Math.max(ldepth, rdepth);
        }
        else {
            int value = Math.min(ldepth, rdepth);
            minmalFound = Math.min(minmalFound, value);
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
        root.left = new TreeNode();
        root.left.right = new TreeNode();
        root.right = new TreeNode();
        root.right.left = new TreeNode();
        root.right.left.right = new TreeNode();
        root.right.left.right.left = new TreeNode();

        Solution.doFaster = false;
        int min = minDepth(root);
        System.out.println("Minimum " + min + " found with " + reccallscount + " recursive calls");


        Solution.doFaster = true;
        min = minDepth(root);
        System.out.println("Minimum " + min + " found with " + reccallscount + " recursive calls with faster approach");
    }
}

class TreeNode {
    TreeNode left = null;
    TreeNode right = null;
}
```

In the code above, I created a tree with left side depth = 3 and right side depth = 5.  I ran `minDepth()` twice; first using your algorithm, and again with my addition. The result is then printed:

```
Minimum 3 found with 11 recursive calls

Minimum 3 found with 5 recursive calls with faster approach
```